# Android - Drag and Drop Between 2 Activities

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

Let's say:
Activity1 contains some items which will be dragged
Activity2 contains some "boxes" which will be filled with Activity1's item. The boxes already have drag listener.
I want to drag item from Activity1 into Activity2
I tried these method:

1. I implement `onLongClickListener()` on Activity1 items and use `startDrag()` there. Then I open Activity2. I could make the drag shadow appear but the boxes cannot receive the item. In fact, they doesn't respond to any `DragEvent`.
2. I implement `onLongClickListener()` on Activity1 items, but only to pass the data into Activity2. Then I use `startDrag()` when Activity2 start(specifically in `onResume()`). Here, the shadow not appear and the boxes doesn't respond to any `DragEvent`.

Is there any way to make this possible?

Comment: Try to use `ViewPager` on single activity with `Fragment`'s. More information: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its possible using two fragment of view pager instead of 2 activity and you can set logic of drag and drop in onTouch() or dispatchTouch().

```
 @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

using dispatchTouch() in activity of fragment or

```
 viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

using touch event of view pager you can set drag and drop logic within inside.

I hope this idea can help you.

Comment: Hi Ketan, why when I drag a view from an activity to another activity, the getLocalState returns null, though I set it to an object in the source activity during the startDrag

Comment: What If I don't want to use fragments and I want to used drag and drop between activities, how could I solve this problem

Comment: for that, you have to implement logic like open new activity with no animation when some particular x and y coordinate match during drag view and also after open new activity, same view regenerate in that activity

Comment: May be is it possible using window manager And that is not proper compare to drag and drop in fragment. But why should you not use fragment instend of activity ..?

Comment: Because when I was building the project I was following the old school, and moving to fragments will require a lot of changes in the application logic, but most importantly, i don't know how to use fragments LOL

Comment: Ketan If you could help me about this matter, please check my question here and offer me your opinion, as I said it would be complicated to re-structure just to solve this problem. Thank you in advance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711596/drag-and-drop-not-working-between-2-activities-on-all-devices/52712394#52712394