# Drag and Drop not working between 2 activities on some devices

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I use the following code to drag a view from an activity to another activity within my application. Knowing that the second activity (That receives drop event) is not created / alive when the drag starts.

**It works good on**

Samsung Note 3 Android 5 API 21, 
Samsung Note 4 Android 6.0.1 API 23

**but not working on**

ASUS ZenPad 8.0 Android 5.1.1 API 22,
Le Max 2 Android 6.0 API 23

Your thoughts are appreciated.

**Starting Drag operation:**

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> aParent, View aView, int aPos, long aID) {

    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(aView);

    Intent intent = prepDNDIntent();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        aView.startDragAndDrop(ClipData.newIntent(DRAG_N_DROP_DESCRIPTION, intent), shadowBuilder, null, 0);
    } else {
        aView.startDrag(ClipData.newIntent(DRAG_N_DROP_DESCRIPTION, intent), shadowBuilder, null, 0);
    }


    startMainActivity();

    finishThisActivity();

    return true;
}
```

**Receiving Drop Operation**

```
public boolean validDragNDropOperation(View aView, DragEvent aEvent){
    boolean status = false;

    ClipDescription clipDescription = aEvent.getClipDescription();
    if (clipDescription != null && clipDescription.getLabel().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(DRAG_N_DROP_DESCRIPTION)) {
        status = true;
    }

    return status;
}


public boolean onDrag(View aView, DragEvent aEvent) {

    switch (aEvent.getAction()) {
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

               This is not called on some devices

               return validDragNDropOperation(aView, aEvent, false);

          case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                 break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Knowing that I set both Activities to android:launchMode="standard" and to "singleTask"** but I ended with the same result.

**EDIT**

During testing, I used an AlertDialog that holds the views being dragged (Instead of using activity), and I faced the same problem, when dragging the view from the AlertDialog to the Activity (That owns the AlertDialog), ACTION_DRAG_STARTED not called.